# Looking for a temporary file storage on post back

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload, postback

In my webpage their are four controls, a `FileUploader`, `combobox`, `TextBox` and a `Button`.In the scenario the `comboBox` causes `Post Back` and button's click will save the content to the `DataBase`

so when i upload a file and change anything in the comboBox will `Reset` the `fileUploader`. i can't avoid the post back of the comboBox, so  is their any way to store the `fileUpload.PostedFile` while `Post back`?

Am trying to do something like this:

```
 Dim tempUpload As New FileUpload
 If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
    tempUpload = DirectCast(FileUpload1, FileUpload)
 End If
```

But it will also reset on post back, so that i had tried it in the `init` event but not result as expected. can anyone help me to recover from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all who make a try on this.. finally i found the solution

When we declare a variable like `Dim tempUpload As New FileUpload` it is reset in page load so change it as `Public Shared tempUpload As New FileUpload` it will retains its value even after the page load, hence the code becomes:

```
Public Shared tempUpload As New FileUpload '<-- change is here
If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
    tempUpload = DirectCast(FileUpload1, FileUpload)
End If
```